# Remove all duplicate and the original elements from a list

Tags: list, collections, salesforce, apex

I have a list of sObject elements. I want to remove the duplicate element having the same record name along with the original record .

Like suppose if I have a list of element having record names as 
Chair1,Chair2,Chair3,Chair4,Chair5,Chair6,Chair7,Chair1,Chair2

I want to print a list having only the elements that have no duplicates.For this case I should get the list Chair3,Chair4,Chair5,Chair6,Chair7.

I am using the below code to achieve this functionality.But I am getting thw records as : Chair1,Chair2,Chair3,Chair4,Chair5,Chair6,Chair7.

In ideal case we should not get the records Chair1,Chair2 as these already have duplicate records.

```
List <Chair__c> chairList = [SELECT
                             ID,
                             Name
                             FROM Chair__c
                             ORDER BY Name ASC];
System.debug('chairListOrderbyName::'+chairList);

List <String> chairNameList = new List <String>();

for(Integer i = 0; i < chairList.size();i++) {

    for(Integer j = 0;j < chairList.size();j++) {

    if(chairList[i].Name.equalsIgnoreCase(chairList[j].Name) && i != j) {

        chairList.remove(i);
        chairList.remove(j);
    }
}
}
System.debug('chairList::'+chairList);
```

Answer (score 0):

If names is really all you need you could do it with pure SOQL using `GROUP BY` and [`HAVING`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_having.htm). Something like

```
SELECT Name
FROM Chair__c
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(Id) = 1 // only unique entries
```

If you need full sObjects then I'd make a helper `Set<String>` and loop through results. If name isn't in the set - add it. But if it already is there -> remove it!

Actually let's make it Map, similar idea...

```
Map<Set, Chair__c> chairs = new Map<Set, Chair__c>();
for(Chair__c c : [SELECT ...]){
    if(chairs.containsKey(c.Name)){
        chairs.remove(c.Name);
    } else {
        chairs.put(c.Name, c);
    }
}
System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(chairs));
System.debug(chairs.values());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `Set<String>` instead of `List<String>`.Refer below solution

```
List <Chair__c> chairList = [SELECT
                             ID,
                             Name
                             FROM Chair__c
                             ORDER BY Name ASC];

Set<String> chairNameSet = new Set<String>();
for(String item: chairList ) {
    chairNameSet.add(item);
}
```